# google map for a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add google maps for my form, so after they enter the address they can view map and after that maps latitude and longitude submitted to the database. So far I couldn't implement it. I tried it on jsfiddle and it worked. But when i try to add to the page it not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/

Here is the full page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htmllang-"en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My First Guide</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }  
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#address").change(function() {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var add = $("#address").val();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': add}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                myOptions);
          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }; 
    });​
</script>
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">My First Guide</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Write a review</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Talk</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Events</a></li>
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                    <!--You can put class="search-query" too.-->
                    <input type="text" class=".navbar-search" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- div container -->
    </div><!-- div navbar-inner -->
  </div><!-- navbar navbar-fixed-top -->


<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Submit Business Place</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Business Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">
                    <p class="help-block">Please specify the name of business.(May
                        be it is a brand name)</p><br />
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Address</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="ad">
                        <p class="help-block">To use lines please specify
                            &lsaquo;br/&rsaquo; tag.</p><br/>
                            <div id="map"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Description</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Categories</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01">
                        <p class="help-block">Use comma as a separator.</p><br />
                    </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>


</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But here is javascript stuff.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#address").change(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var add = $("#address").val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': add}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            myOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}; 
});​
</script>
```

And here is the div where i add my map.

```
<div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Address</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="ad">
                        <p class="help-block">To use lines please specify
                            &lsaquo;br/&rsaquo; tag.</p><br/>
                            <div id="map"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `pJgyu` doesn't seem to have much to do with maps. And in any case, it works. There's far too much code to wade through here: could you give a link to your example which doesn't work? And what does "not working" mean? What happens? What do you expect to see instead? How do we reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a quick scan of your code and there seem to be some basic coding problems:

1. You appear to create your map in an intialize function, but your initialize function appears to be embedded within the larger .change() callback function; I do not see how your map is ever going to be displayed.
2. Your JavaScript code is focused on a jQuery search for an element with the id: ***address***, but there does not appear to be an element with that id in your markup.
3. The label you define that contains the text *Address* says that it is a label for: **input01**, but you have 2 distinct elements in your markup that have been assigned the id: **input01**.
4. There are multiple labels that have been marked as being the label for: **input01**.
5. All of the script tags you have defined at the bottom of your file are missing the **type** attribute.

I think you have too many basic coding errors and it looks like you may have possibly garbled the code during the process of submitting it for review? It's hard to tell, but I hope my feedback is helpful and will help you to get closer to your goal.